# Adding Units to argparse

Tags: python, argparse

Presently I have

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(formatter_class=argparse.ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter)
group = parser.add_argument_group("Calibration Options")
group.add_argument('-c', '--calibration', default=False, action="store_true", help="Calibrate Gear", dest="calibrate")
group.add_argument('--startFreq', default=400, type=int, help="Start Frequency [MHz]", dest="calStart")
```

This produces this output

```
Calibration Options:
  -c, --calibration     Calibrate Gear (default: False)
  --startFreq           Start Frequency (MHz) (default: 400)
```

This is ok, but I would like the 'Units' to be included with the default value like..

```
Calibration Options:
  -c, --calibration     Calibrate Gear (default: False)
  --startFreq           Start Frequency (default: 400 MHz)
```

is there anyway of doing this or reason I shouldn't do it?

Comment: I personally think it's unnecessary to include the units after the default value.

Comment: reason not to: now I try to input `--startfreq 100 MHz`

Comment: If you want to include the `MHz` in the default value than the default value shouldn't be an `int`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your own `%(default)s` in the help line.  All that the specialized formatter is doing adding that string to the help.

```
group.add_argument('--startFreq', default=400, type=int, help="Start Frequency (default: %(default)s MHz)", dest="calStart")
```

I would also use:

```
`group.add_argument('-c', '--calibration', action="store_true", help="Calibrate Gear (default: False)", dest="calibrate")
```

The builtin default for `store_true` is False, but `%(default)s` does not capture that.

`argparse.ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter` is a convenience tool.  There's nothing that it does that you can't do just as well in the `help` string.  `%(default)s` is most useful when the default value might a variable, something that is not known when you define the argument and its `help` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

If you make the type of your start frequency a string then you can default it to "400 MHz" - you can then post parse it to the number you need - it you make even like to look at having the possibility of parsing the units so that the user could call your script with 100k or 200kHz, etc.